# Wrapping a callback API and listening for errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I'm wrapping a callback API like this:

```
    export function process(data: string): Observable<Result> {
      return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Result>) => {
        call(data, result => {
            if (result.errors) {
              observer.error(result.errors);
            }
            else {
              observer.next(result);  
            }
            observer.complete();
          },
        });
      });
    }
```

I'd like to be able to call:

```
process(data).subscribe(data=>doStuffWithData).catch(e=>performErrorHandling);
```

[I've been reading through the documentation on catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html).

The example ends like this:

```
//output: 'I caught: This is an error'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

So now it looks like we either get the result or the error when subscribing.  Is it possible to separate the value from the error with something like this:

```
process.subscribe(data=>doStuffWithData).catch(e=>performErrorHandling);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error handler is passed as the second argument to subscribe now (`subscribe(v=>{...}, e=>handleTheError`):

```
result.subscribe(v=>console.log(v), error=>console.log(error));
```

For more information see [rxjs-error-handling](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) from Angular University.

Here's their HTTP example:

```
http$.subscribe(
  res => console.log('HTTP response', res),
  err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
  () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
);
```

Use the [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) operator when you want to emit an alternative fallback value.